# R tidyverse - data_grid .model parameter

Tags: r, tidyverse, modelr

following an update of my R environment, I keep receiving this error:

Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'G' not found

Documentation says: 
"A model. If supplied, any predictors needed for the model not present in ... will be filled in with "typical" values."

This seems to work for the given example in the documentation. However, there seems to be a problem with the given example below.
There was no problem with previous versions.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hexbin)
library(modelr)
smaller <- diamonds %>% filter(carat < 3)
mod_diamond2 <- lm(price ~ carat + color + cut + clarity, data = smaller)
grid <- smaller %>%  data_grid(cut, .model = mod_diamond2) %>% 
add_predictions(mod_diamond2)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried the code in RStudio 1.0.153 and R version 3.3.2 and i don't get any error.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Well, I have RStudio 1.0.153 and R 3.4.1 running. tidyverse is also the latest cran package.